# Performance issue when I try to attribute title to DropDownlist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I am using below code to select all dropdowns using jQuery and attributing title value to it.

```
jq("select option").each(function () {
   jq(this).attr({ 'title': jq(this).html() });
});
```

But the problem is if there are a huge number of values in DropDown it is taking lots of time to attribute title value.

How can I improve the performance of my code?

Comment: do u want all title `value` in an array??

Comment: yes..just to let u know i am using the above code to show the tooltip for the text in DropDown

Comment: Is it not possible to do this on server side? Would make more sense

Comment: Actually i am using asp.net mvc dropdown. I am not getting any options to add the title at server Side

Answer (score 2):

Using this should increase performance as it acts on the direct object, rather than going through jQuery:

#### Option 1: increase jQuery performance

```
$('select > option').each(function() {
    this.title = this.text;
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZJaKF/

#### Option 2: use "vanilla Javascript"

Not using `.each` will increase performance as well, as internally the anonymous function has to be called each iteration. If you really want performance just use "vanilla" Javascript:

```
var options = document.getElementById('selectId').options,
    i = options.length;

while (--i > -1) options[i].title = options[i].text;
```

#### Option 3: use server-side implentation

While outputting the form just set the title attribute to the contents of the option. This would be the fastest solution.

[See here for a comparison of benchmarks using different techniques](http://jsperf.com/set-title-on-options-from-text)

Comment: No problem. Please remember to click the "tick" button next to this answer to mark it as accepted :)